# Google Group - Clone or back up a group on admin console

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

We have a large emergency notification list (Google group) consisting of 75000 members. The membership of this group is maintained through a daily sync with enterprise identity management tables using GSuite Admin SDK - Group Settings API. Can anybody suggest an easy way to create a backup group for this list directly on Google Admin console. If the  original list lost its membership it took 14 hours to bring the list up via API. Hence the need for a backup group. This backup google group must be ready to send the emergency alert message in case some thing happened to original group membership during daily sync.

Comment: I think this can be done using [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) or you could also use this tool - [ggbackup](https://github.com/lindegroup/ggbackup) which will also create a backup of Google Groups with their settings and members. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rebot. 'ggbackup' I understand will only create csv file with membership for a group. To create a ready to post google group consisting of 75000 members via API using the csv file will take the same 14 hours and the API quota limits will not assure 100% membership. I have used only API.I do not have permissions to GAM. But I guess admins can use this CSV file to create a new backup group. Am I correct? Any idea how long it may take to add 75,000 members to a group using GAM command line?

Comment: I also found a 'sync' command in GAM documentation: gam update group 'backupgooglegroup@example.com' sync member  group 'originalgooglegroup@example.com'. Do you think this will work for my purpose?

Comment: Is there a way to automate GAM command by cron so as to create a backup every week?